# With the same routes, but calling different controller Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can I use the same routes but access different controllers? I want my url like this

```
example.com/article-name/
example.com/category-name/
```

My routes are:

```
$route['([^/]+)/?'] = 'Article/index/$1';
$route['([^/]+)/?'] = 'Category/index/$1';
```

I cannot find out how to do this.

Comment: See this search results: [link](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=With+the+same+routes%2C+but+calling+different+controller+Codeigniter&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN725IN725&oq=With+the+same+routes%2C+but+calling+different+controller+Codeigniter&aqs=chrome..69i57.679j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: The same routes like `$route['([^/]+)/?']` are impossible to point to different controllers unless you differ the parameters or point by random.

Comment: or can I use $route[(:any)]? Please tell me your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Change the .htaccess file.

Then, in config.php change line no:38 as given below

`$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: How to change htaccess file? Please say it particularly.